# TSQL - how to read datetimes from files with xp_dirtree

Tags: .net, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, directory

I'm working with a TSQL-script which uses ***xp_dirtree*** to pick up a file name from a directory with multiple bak-files, and then restores to a database using selected filename and the directory.

However, I want to be able to select the MOST RECENT file from said folder. Currently, the script only picks the top after ordering by filename.

The folder might look something like this:

```
------------
File1.BAK

File2.BAK

File3.BAK

File4.BAK
------------
```

My script currently looks like this:

```
        DECLARE @dir varchar(60)
        SET @dir = 'C:\TestFolder\'

        CREATE TABLE #DirectoryTree (
               id int IDENTITY(1,1)
              ,subdirectory nvarchar(512)
              ,depth int
              ,isfile bit);

        INSERT #DirectoryTree (subdirectory,depth,isfile)
        EXEC master.sys.xp_dirtree @dir,1,1;

        DECLARE @file varchar(60) = 
            (SELECT TOP 1 subdirectory
            FROM #DirectoryTree
            WHERE isfile = 1 AND RIGHT(subdirectory,4) = '.BAK'
            ORDER BY subdirectory DESC)

        SET @dir = @dir+@file
        PRINT '--Selected file: "'+@dir+'"'
        GO
        DROP TABLE #DirectoryTree

        --restores from file
        restore database TESTDB
        from disk = @dir
        with replace, file = 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dirtree does not return that information. Xp_cmdshell does and it has to be enabled on your instance which your dba may, or may not, allow. If it is here is a solution:

```
create table #files (name varchar(500))

insert into #files
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'dir *.exe';

    -- find name after list space in string....
select name, REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(name),0,CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(name)))) 
from #files 
     -- dates start with numeric --check assumption carefully...
     where isnumeric(left(name,1))=1 
       --order by date desc       --
    order by CAST(left(name,17) as datetime) desc
```